# Compositing colors and textures in webgl

Tags: webgl

How to do color compositing in webgl? I am not sure what to search for exactly maybe I am missing a word. I want to be able to draw a color or texture as overlay. For example, here I tried to add black overlay with 0.2 opacity but instead of using color directly I am substracting opacity. If I want to use different color as overlay, I will have to use different work around for it. How can I overlay/composite different colors or textures without using any work around? [Shadertoy link](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Ntf3WN)

```
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord ) {
    vec2 uv = fragCoord/iResolution.xy;

    vec4 col = texture(iChannel0, uv);
    vec4 overlay = vec4(0., 0., 0., 0.2);

    col -= overlay.a;
    
    fragColor = col;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to darken the texture color towards black, you could use a simple multiplication:

```glsl
vec4 col = texture(iChannel0, uv);
col *= 0.8; // 20% darker
```

Or if you'd like to use a color, you could also multiply those

```glsl
vec4 col = texture(iChannel0, uv);
vec4 tint = vec4(1.0, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0); // Orange
col *= tint;
```

There are a lot of ways to blend colors together. Another alternative to create smooth gradients between colors is [by using the `mix()` function](https://thebookofshaders.com/glossary/?search=mix). There is no one answer.

Comment: Thanks for responding, ya blending works but doesn't work with black color as I would want. I came up with another method of adding color to texture like `(color.rgb - 0.5) * color.a;` but this does not work with gray color. What can someone do if they want universal solution to overlay any color? Any topics/discussions you can suggest so I can gather more information?

Comment: "Overlay" is a very vague term, and it could mean any number of math equations. For example, [Photoshop has 31 different blending modes](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/blending-modes.html), each one is achieved through different calculations.

Comment: Ya my question is vague, I will try to clarify. Let's say you have two textures. You want to draw texture1 first and draw texture2 on top on of it but at half opacity in same shader, how can you do that? In photoshop if you take these 2 textures as layers and reduce the opacity of top layer, the final image will look natural and will work with any images. How can I do same in single fragment shader?

Comment: Did you look at the mix() function I linked in my answer? `col = mix(texture1, texture2, 0.5);`

Comment: Oh ya I tried but it was ignoring opacity, but just realized that I can use opacity of new color to get desired results. `col = mix(texture, color, color.a);`. Thanks!